# Reading Firebase Data: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios11

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
  let user = User(username: username)
  print(username)
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

I copied the code from the Firebase tutorial but got: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

If I changed the code into:

```
ref?.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
  let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
  let user = User(username: username)
  print(username)
  }) { (error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

The `username` doesn't print.
How could I fix it? And what is the best way to retrieve data?

Comment: Any exclamation mark can cause a crash. According to the code `ref` is `nil`.

Comment: Can you move print (username) above your  let user = User(username: username) statement?

Comment: @stevenpcurtis This makes no difference. The database reference instance is not assigned to `ref`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ref variable should be

```
var ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Comment: Thank you very much Elhoej! That was the solution!